# проверка строки на содержимое в виде числа (скорость)

Tags: java, строки, циклы, java-stream, преобразование-типов

есть строка и надо проверить ее содержимое на наличие числа, есть три подхода:
1

```
public static boolean isNumber(String source) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(source);
        return true
    } catch(...) {
        //
    }
    return false;
}
```

2

```
public static boolean isNumber(String source) {
    for(int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

3

```
public static boolean isNumber(String source) {
    return IntStream.range(0, source.length()).allMatch(i -> Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i)));
}
```

вопрос: какой из них будет быстрее?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возьмите да сами потестируйте )  Вангую, что вариант с `try/catch` будет самый медленный, затем третий вариант, потом второй. Но надо пробовать. И ещё будет зависеть от того, реально вы числа проверяете или нет. И какой длины строки.

Comment: я уже протестировал))) с исключениями - 2е место

Comment: Ну тогда оформите свой ответ )